# Creating a property with the object of the same class in c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

What I am trying is the following:

```
public class AHME
{
    public string elementName { get; set; }
    public long? elementID { get; set; }
    public AHME[] children { get; set; }

    public static AHME[] GetAHME()
    {
        var listS = new List<AHME>();

        using (var db = new DBEntities())
        {
            AHME sList = db.Stnd.Select(s => new AHME
            {
                elementID = s.ID,
                elementName = s.Name,
            }).ToList();
            
            listS.Add(sList);

            var listT = new List<AHME>();

            using (var db = new DBEntities())
            {
                AHME tList = db.Tr.Join(db.Us, t => t.ID, u => u.ID, (t, u) => new AHME
                {
                    elementID = t.ID,
                    elementName = u.FirstNames + " " + u.LastName,
                    children=listS.ToArray(),
                });

                listT.Add(tList).ToList();
            }
            
            return listT.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

But I am getting errors like:

> Cannot implicitly convert type '`System.Collections.Generic.List<LSB.HM.AHME>`' to '`LSB.HM.AHME`'
>
> Cannot implicitly convert type '`System.Linq.IQueryable<LSB.HM.AHME>`' to '`LSB.HM.AHME`'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Additionally, for "`AHME sList`" if I could use var type like `var sList`,
then its throwing error that:

> `<LSB.HM.AHME>.Add` has some invalid arguements

Comment: Try `List<AHME> sList = ` at the start of your query.

Comment: Can you indicate which *lines* are generating those errors? That information should be in the compiler output. And don't just say a line number - add comments at the end of the lines of code where the errors occur.

Comment: I think you should learn basics of C#, before starting to dabble with LINQ.

Comment: If you edit again, please note that several of us have been trying to fix your formatting because `<>` angle brackets don't show up in plain narrative text, we have to mark it up as code.

Comment: @Euphoric - Why do you think OP doesn't know the basics of C#?

Comment: I think the `.ToList()` returns `List<AHME>`...So use `List<AHME>` in in place of `AHME` in the 10th line[as Tim commented]...or If you use `var` cast it to `List<AHME>` then do the `.Add(sList)`...

Answer (score 5):

You're trying to assign a `List<AHME>` object to an `AHME` variable. Try it like this:

```
        var sList = db.Stnd.Select(s => new AHME
        {
            elementID = s.ID,
            elementName = s.Name,
        }).ToList();
```

Same for the `Join` line.

Comment: @Stuart I consider this a tie. Have my +1.

Answer (score 4):

The problems lie in the blocks like:

```
        AHME sList = db.Stnd.Select(s => new AHME
        {
            elementID = s.ID,
            elementName = s.Name,
        }).ToList();
```

You cannot cast an `IList<T>` to a `T`.

The easiest solution is to use `var`

```
        var sList = db.Stnd.Select(s => new AHME
        {
            elementID = s.ID,
            elementName = s.Name,
        }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all and Writwick.

I have used a foreach loop to iterate over the var sList and add the items in the sList in the ListS and conceptually I think it should be like that, as sList contains list of objects and those require to be added one by one to the ListS.

Comment: Also see : [`.AddRange()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc.aspx). You dont need to `loop` to add a `List<T>` to another `List<T>` where both `T` are of same type, which in your case is `AHME`.